# Question about filesteam data and its varbinary(max) value in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone advise in detail what does the varbinary(max) value represent if say a BLOB file (.pdf) is stored in the file system through the filestream attribute in sql server?

And how does it get copied across databases on different servers by using the usual T-SQL queries?

Many thanks.

Best regards,

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. `BLOB` is a data type, not a file type. `VARBINARY(MAX)` would store the bytes of the .pdf, it would just be data at that point. What specifically are you asking with regard to copying it across databases? Is this replication or something along those lines?

Comment: Hi, I mean doing a insert from table1 on server 1 to table2 on server2. We have copied it across. Hope it is clear. How does that work? But I try to understand the behind-the scene thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing `BLOB` data using a [FILESTREAM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) setup enables you to store your documents on disk while keeping your document's reference information in the database. Sometimes it is advised to use this approach if your file storage solution is cheap while your database storage is not, but it really depends on your requirements.
If you are working with small `BLOB` files, it might be better to leave the `FILESTREAM` setup alone as it comes with some overhead configuring and maintaining this. For instance in your comment's example to copy over data from one server to another.